# Inconsistent result of clustering number order (R)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, random-seed

I have parcels with the type of crop culture for each year for 5 years. I want to create a clustering of my parcels which would indicate the type of crop rotation based on the number of occurences of each crop type during the 5 years on a plot.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:100,  # Adding a column for IDs
    matrix(sample(0:5, 100 * 15, replace = TRUE), ncol = 15)
)
```

I used this method to do the clustering (based on inertia, I know that my clustering can discriminate itself into 8 clusters):

```
clust = stats::hclust(vegan::vegdist(data %>% select(X1:X15)), method = "ward.D2")
clust$labels = data$ID

groups = stats::cutree(clust, 8)
data$cluster = as.factor(groups)

names_clust = data.frame(cluster = c(1:8), nom_cluster = c("Maize Rotation", "Beet low / diverse rotation", "Beet main rotation", "Legumes dominant", "Permanent grassland type", "Grassland dominant", "Fallow", "Fruit trees / Vegetables"))

data = data %>% 
  merge(names_clust, by = "cluster", all.x = T)
```

The clustering is always accurate, the corresponding parcels go well together, but the corresponding number for each cluster isn't consistent everytime I run the code, which does give me a problem when naming the clusters by their "character" name.

I tried the set.seed() function thinking the group numbering was random, but it does not have appeared to work.

Comment: After using your `clust...` code block _without_ `set.seed`, replicating 100 times, I have found no differences. Where are you seeing differences? Since you're using random data in this question, are you using `set.seed` before or after you create the random data?

Comment: I'm using my own data, this is just a example data here, and the `set.seed` function that I tried was just before the `clust...` code block. Problem must come from my original dataset on which I did a few coding just before this step. I'm going to try to look at it more closely. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As a general rule of safety, I would not depend on the name or order of clusters when comparing two (or more) clustering outcomes. One normally establishes a mapping between clusters (from two different clusterings) using the confusion matrix between the two clusterings.

Comment: `hclust` is a deterministic method up to the order of the data. That is, if you reorder your data then you will get different cluster labels. Everything being fixed, you are guaranteed to get the same results. Maybe you want to share a snippet of your real code?

Comment: After running code a few times, the outcome doesn't seem to change, so I guess the problem is coming from me reordering my data. @thothal The code preceding this block is quite huge (like 100 lines of code) so sharing it would probably be a issue.